# Why doesn't my Textbox react on IsMouseOver in the Style for the ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary

So I am trying to style my TextBox a little bit, the idea was that I wanted to style the BorderBrush when hovering over the TextBox but for some reason it didnt change the Border, so I tried changing the Background as well, and same thing there. That's when I realized it doesnt react to the `IsMouseOver` but it does set the background and everything else that I did, it's just the event `IsMouseOver` that it's not reacting to.

The Control

```
<TextBox Width="700"
         Height="340"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
         Margin="0,0,230,140"
         Foreground="#8bf502"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Style="{DynamicResource TextboxStyle}"/>
```

The Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextboxStyle">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border Background="#424242">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `TargetName` and a `BorderThickness`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextboxStyle">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="2" Background="#424242">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There is no `Border` unless you set the `BorderThickness` property of it to something else than `0`.

Comment: Oh wow ofcouse! How else will it know what to change the property of!

Comment: And ofcourse, adding the property `BorderThickness` to actually be able to see the border since it's 0 by default.

Comment: I can't write in the textbox, why would that be?

Comment: That's another question really. But your template is missing a ScrollViewer element.

Comment: Ohh okay, I'll look into it for a bit and if I can't figure it out I'll be back.

Answer (score 1):

To change the Background of the Border, give the Border a Name and add TargetName="MyBorder" to the Setter

Answer (score 1):

You are using a custom `Template`, but your template does not apply the border properties of the templated `TextBox`.  Try adding the following to the `Border` element in your template:

```
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
```

There's actually a few ways you can approach this: use template bindings and put the trigger in the `Style`; use template bindings and put the trigger in the template; use an explicit target element and put the trigger in the template (as others here have suggested); etc.  The "right" approach depends on how/if you want the control to respond when the property is changed.  For example: if someone sets a new `BorderBrush` directly on the `TextBox`, do you want that to supersede your orange hover effect or not?  It's worth reading up on [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) of dependency properties to understand the implications of how and where certain properties are set.

It's worth noting that your template is incomplete and won't work if you want the text to be editable (or selectable).  A `TextBox` expects its template to have a specially named `ScrollViewer` where an editable text view can be injected.  Try replacing your `ContentPresenter` with the following:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
```

Note that the `x:Name` attribute must match exactly.

Comment: I can't write in the textbox, why would that be?

Comment: Because your template is incomplete.  A `TextBox` expects its template to have a specially named scroll viewer where an editable text view can be injected.  Try replacing your `ContentPresenter` with the following: `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />`.  Note that the `x:Name` attribute must match exactly.